# Websocket/SocketIO for Django + ExtJS

Tags: django, extjs, gevent-socketio

I have multiple stores in ExtJS based application which I wish to update from Server (Websockets/SocketIO). The backend is Django. The only production-ready solution in Django for Websockets seems to be gevent-socketio.

I explored Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket but I am not sure how to make it work with gevent-socketio based Django backend. Can anyone suggest a way forward with this or any other plugin for websockets in Django? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is still relevant; if so, I don't think gevent-socketio is the only "production ready" solution. Have a look at [SwampDragon](http://swampdragon.net/tutorial/part-1-here-be-dragons-and-thats-a-good-thing/). Otherwise, if you resolved this, add your solution as an answer please.